# Beginner feeling overwhelmed with the whole of Programming

Tags: c#

As the title suggests, I'm feeling overwhelmed with the whole scope of Programming as I have no clue where it will lead and just what I'll be able to accomplish

For the last weeks or so I've been tackling on programming with books and tutorials, I've gone as far as learning conditionals and so forth on C#, even though I could not get myself to focus on it as much as I wanted to as a question in the back of my mind always remained, and that is;

**Where am I going?**

Where exactly am I going with all of this?

There is just so much in programming yet I know so little.

Like, let's say I do end up learning a language from start to finish, there the question remains; now what?

How do I use that knowledge to make **real** stuff and not just some cool tricks?

How can I relate what I've learned and make 'real stuff' from it? 
I feel like what I'm learning so far is so, how do I say it: that it's all just a scratch on the surface, and I feel like the rest of what I learn about the language will be just a scratch on the surface as well. It doesn't feel like I'm learning anything profoundly, just some cool tricks.

Yes I can write a if statement, so what? It feels like I have gained no real knowledge but that I can only do that cool trick. That's it.

I don't really know how to put it in words, but hopefully I'm making sense

Comment: I think that practice is the best way. Find a tutorial on the web. Or, visit MOOC sites such as http://coursera.com

Comment: Start making simple scripts and slowly make them do more and more. You may surprise yourself!

Comment: I empathize with your plight, but fact is a discussion of this sort isn't really on-topic on this web site. There are other, more discussion-oriented forums and communities where your concerns are better-addressed (or maybe you can find some sympathetic conversation in the chat feature here on StackOverflow).

Comment: @PeterDuniho My apologies. Should've looked around more but noticing now that it's not for question of this nature. 

I think that's what I will do, topy and John Smith, maybe I'll gain more of a sense of what I'm doing that way, if not I'll just ask again somewhere appropriate.

Thank you for taking the time to answer everyone

Comment: Realize that as soon as you learn a language, you've already learned bits of other languages. The first 2 languages are probably the hardest. Once you begin picking up on the common patterns, the idea of picking up a new language is exciting. Don't worry about making big things until you actually know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer that I could think of is for you to tackle what you want. If you want to make games and simply starting out. Then tackle Unity as it uses C# but not really hard to code as the game engine already took care of it.

If you're in to Website. I suggest Learning the MVC ASP.net C# basics is a core fundamental for you to grasp all the tutorials that they are offering that is why every time you dig in to a MVC and C# Tutorial, you must have a knowledge on the basic Coding.

This is not really the correct case for everyone as some have patience working on the books, stick to it till the end before using the knowledge on creating games, making Website or what so ever. But everyone is different and everyone as an anxiety feeling of "I want to do this now, later the basics" or "I need to learn the basics because, I am afraid of jumping ahead". It really depends on how you would feel. Because you can be both at an alternating time. For me, it is an never ending learning and you must breath and eat Coding if you really want to take a grasp on it.

In my Experience, i have completed the C# 3.0 main core and when I try to apply it in MVC ASP.net is easy as pie. Applying it to make a game in Unity3D is really easy as well.

Only then when I completed the C# 3.0 made me realize how important it is to learn the main languange and it encourages me to learn other programming language that is not originally my goal.

In the end, this is all I can offer you. NO ONE CAN TELL YOU HOW YOU SHOULD DO SOMETHING OR WHAT IS THE BEST THING FOR YOU, ONLY YOU KNOW WHAT IS BEST FOR YOU.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually pretty helpful, I think I'm going to do just that actually (Unity with C)

Maybe I just need something I wanna do and focus on it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The trick to being a programmer is breaking problems down in to smaller chunks.  Your problem is you feel adrift in a sea of technologies and are at the bottom of a gradual learning curve (people typically would say its a steep learning curve but they're using the phrase wrongly!).

So break it down, what kind of programmer do you want to be, what lights your fuse?  Web?  Windows?  Working with databases?  Artificial intelligence?  Playing with Web 2.0 interfaces?

I think you'll have most success if you have a goal, not just some hokey goal like 'learn web programming', but something you really want to build, or play with.  If you don't want to build anything or play with anything, then maybe it isn't for you?

So, if you're interested in Windows apps, in C#, think of something small that you could do.  So, just pick anything, doesn't have to be a viable product, just something for yourself, an address book, a recipe book, a reminder app.  Doing that will give you focus, so you stop feeling adrift in an endless sea of tech.   I've been doing it professionally for 15 years or so, and there's a lot of languages, platforms etc etc that I just do not have the time to explore, it really feels like everything has exploded in the last 10 years.